# How to run a function twice and save output for comparison?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, cypress

I have created a function that compares two arrays and makes sure they are not equal to each other. I run the function twice but I must admit it is a very poor design, however, it was the only way I could get it to work. Is there an easier way to accomplish the same thing? Maybe deepcloning with lodash? Here is my go at it.

```
let callCount = 0;
let values = [];
let values2 = [];
const getData = () => {
        const chart = [{ //dynamic: changes the id numbers on second call
              items: [{
                 id: 1,
                 name: 'foo'
              }, {
                 id: 2,
                 name: 'bar'
              }, {
                 id: 3,
                 name: 'bar'
              }, {
                 id: 4,
                 name: 'bar'
              }]
             }];
        if (callCount < 1) { //if and for block cannot be extracted for various reasons
            for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                const arr = chart[i].items[0];
                arr.forEach((element) => {
                    values.push(element.id);
                });
            }
            callCount++;
            return values;
        }
        if (callCount >= 1) {
            for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                const arr = chart[i].items[0];
                arr.forEach((element) => {
                    values2.push(element.id);
                });
            }
            expect(values).to.not.eq(values2);
        }
};


it ('Comparing two arrays', function () {
    getData()
    // logic that will change effectively change some of the values of `chart`
    getData()
    // is successful but wildly inefficient
}
```

Is there an easier way using Javascript to do the same thing without counting the number of times the function is called and running the same thing again?

Comment: _"I run the function twice but I must admit it is a very poor design, however, it was the only way I could get it to work. Is there an easier way to accomplish the same thing?"_ ... implement the function properly at first place, thus there is no need of running it twice, thus also no need to find another hacky solution which fixes this rather unusual design choice.

Comment: @PeterSeliger I don't know another way of doing it other than calling it twice. However, I also know that there is most likely one as calling something twice is bad practice

Comment: `//dynamic: changes the id numbers on second call` no it doesn't. `//if and for block cannot be extracted for various reasons` that you don't. Your code doesn't represent the problem you're asking us to help you with.

Answer (score 1):

Return the array each time and compare at the end of the sequence,

```js
const getData = () => {
        const chart = [{ //dynamic: changes the id numbers on second call
              items: [{
                 id: 1,
                 name: 'foo'
              }, {
                 id: 2,
                 name: 'bar'
              }, {
                 id: 3,
                 name: 'bar'
              }, {
                 id: 4,
                 name: 'bar'
              }]
             }];
    const arr = chart[i].items[0].map(element => element.id)
    return arr;
};


it ('Comparing two arrays', function () {

    const values1 = getData()

    // logic that will change effectively change some of the values of `chart`

    const values2 = getData()

    expect(values1).to.not.eq(values2);
}
```

I am wondering how `chart` gets changed - is there some `cy.get()` commands involved?

If so you will have to return the result of them and nest the results

```js
it ('Comparing two arrays', function () {
    getData().then(values1 => {

      // logic that will change effectively change some of the values of `chart`

      getData().then(const values2 => {
        expect(values1).to.not.eq(values2);
      })
    })
}
```